# Map of Key to Map in Java

Tags: java

Before I reinvent the wheel does java already have this data structure: `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` as a single type?

I need to be able to call `.get(key)` and it return a `Map<String, String>`.

Or is there a common library that has it?

Comment: `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` is not very complicated. Just use it. BTW: This *is* a "single type".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map of Maps data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093718/map-of-maps-data-structure)

Comment: lol theoritically you can have Map<String,Map<String,Map<String...>>> if you wanted to. heheh

Comment: Another alternative is use a Map<Pair<String, String>, String> and roll your own Pair or use one from for instance Apache Commons.

Comment: Another alternative is Guava's *Table*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645525/map-in-map-in-guava But @Tichodroma is right. You can just use exactly what you described

Comment: I would agree with @vefthym, check out ImmutableTable or Table from Guava, this should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what people have written in the comments (if I may), you have plenty of options here:

- Use exactly what you described, i.e., a `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`, as Tichodroma suggests (after all it's not so complicated).
- Use a `Map<Pair<String,String>, String>` where `Pair` is either a class that you defined, or one of Apache Common's Pair classes, like [this one](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html), as aioobe suggest. Keep in mind, however, that there is a reason [why Java doesn't have a Pair class](http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/03/31/do-we-want-a-java-util-pair/).
- My advice would be to use Guava's [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)`<String,String,String>`, or [ImmutableTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.html) (as Quantas adds), which do exactly what you want. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645525/map-in-map-in-guava) for more details.

Plase, do not upvote/accept this answer, unless you picked the last option.